# jquery $.ajax call succeeds but returns nothing. (jsonp)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#button').click(function() {
       try {
           var json = $.ajax({url : 'http://www.example.com/experimental/service.php', type : 'jsonp', success : function() {alert('success')}});
           alert(json);
        } catch(err) {
           alert(err.description)
        }
        var sjson = JSON.stringify(json);
       $('#display').html(sjson);
   })
})
```

After a button is pressed I get an alert message that says "success" and also one that says undefined, referring to the fact that nothing was returned from the ajax call. I checked the firebug 'net' tab and indeed i get a succesful response from the server of "jsonp1272724228884( {} );" Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would image that `alert(json);` is showing undefined because it is running before the response is received.

Remember that 'ajax' is 'asynchronous', so that alert will go ahead and execute before your `json` value has a chance to be assigned a value.

Furthermore, even if it did work, your `json` variable would simply reference the `XMLHttpRequest` object that was made. If you want to access the data itself, you need to do so in the callback.

```
var json;

$.ajax({
    url : 'http://www.example.com/experimental/service.php', 
    type : 'jsonp', 
    success : function(data) {
                  alert('success');
                  json = data;
                  alert(json);
              }
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

There's also an `error:` callback that you can assign. The callback will execute if the server returns an error code. I assume that is what you intended to replicate with your try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the result right after making the ajax callback, you have to set the `async : false` attribute of ajax call to make it synchronous. As this is usually not what you want to do, you should probably process the response in a different (asynchronous) way.