# Puzzle : finding out repeated element in an Array

Tags: arrays

Size of an array is n.All elements in the array are distinct in the range of [0 , n-1] except two elements.Find out repeated element without using extra temporary array with constant time complexity.

I tried with o(n) like this.

```
   a[]={1,0,0,2,3};
    b[]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    i=0;
    int required;
    while(i<n)
    {
      b[a[i]]++;
      if(b[a[i]==1)
        required=a[i];
    }
    print required;
```

If there is no constraint on range of numbers i.e allowing out of range also.Is  it possible  get o(n) solution without temporary array.

Comment: Is this homework? This isn't really the kind of question for SO. (Unless it's homework.)

Comment: This can be done in `O(1)` time? Are you sure you're not messing it up with linear time? The solution I can think of still requires you to go through n elements.

Comment: @Josh This looks more like an interview question

Comment: Similar to [
Algorithm to find two repeated numbers in an array, without sorting
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555744).

Comment: You cannot solve this problem in constant-time. Since you don't know where the elements are in advance, and no ordering is stipulated, you require at least O(n) time.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta:I tried by taking temporary array of size n-1.I want to reduce the space complexity..

Comment: @Jagan: ok, that's a start. Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Missing `homework` or `interview-question` tag...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750393/jquery-ajax-call-succeeds-but-returns-nothing-jsonp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to find two repeated numbers in an array, without sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555744/algorithm-to-find-two-repeated-numbers-in-an-array-without-sorting)

Comment: Use the original array as a bit mask --- flop the items to neg as you go over the list when you see one you have already changed flip them back and return it. Simple

Comment: @Hogan, that halfway works, as long as you assume the input is writable and that it's a large enough type to have an extra bit available in each slot. What if the array was bytes and `n=255`? You might say you can arrange for this not to be the case, but then what you're doing is actually giving yourself `O(n)` temporary space. So it's cheating.

Comment: @R : I agree it is cheating, but why is a professor giving this kind of question anyway? -- it is not like it will ever help in applied CS.

Comment: I believe it was an interview question, not homework. I don't think it has much value in that context since I wouldn't expect a good programmer to necessarily come up with the answer on the spot, but ability to understand complexity theory and develop algorithms with optimal big-O (not just in time but also in space) has a lot of practical value. If nothing else, experience writing algorithms that do not need temporary space (and thus which have no failure cases) is quite valuable in real-world development.

Comment: @R : Yes understanding complexity and able to write algorithms is useful.  So are questions that actually come up.  For example, one I've seen variations a million times -- db conversion with different codes for state -- how do you convert?  Most of the time it is coded wrong.

Comment: Constant time solution: 

   a[]={1,0,0,2,3};
   return 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look what is first and last number
2. Calculate SUM(1) of array elements without duplicate (like you know that sum of 1...5 = 1+2+3+4+5 = 15. Call it SUM(1)). As AaronMcSmooth pointed out, the formula is `Sum(1, n) = (n+1)n/2`.
3. Calculate SUM(2) of the elements in array that is given to you.
4. Subtract SUM(2) - SUM(1). Whoa! The result is the duplicate number (like if a given array is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, the SUM(2) will be 18. 18 - 15 = 3. So 3 is a duplicate).

Good luck coding!

Comment: This isn't O(1), as it requires you to iterate over not one, but two arrays. Also, having an array without a duplicate counts as having a temporary array.

Comment: @rafe Kettler, you can use the identity Sum(1, n) = (n+1)n/2 for step 2

Comment: I hope you'd optimize step 2... ;-) You should also note that the sum should be unsigned, and it doesn't matter if it wraps modulo `UINT_MAX+1`. Otherwise, the sum of `n` numbers if `O(n)` in space.

Comment: @Aaron: I'm pretty sure OP was incorrect about `O(1)` time and really wanted `O(1)` space. Naively, this sum is `O(n)` in space, but it would be just as good to known the sum modulo `M` where `M>=n` since the difference modulo `M` will be sufficient to determine which number was duplicate. Thankfully, a convenient value for `M` is `UINT_MAX+1`. :-)

Comment: How do you check for dups in step 2 without a temp array?

Comment: @R, that's a good trick. I don't see why it's needed though. Why is accumulating the sum while looping over the array O(n) in space? It seems like it would only require one `unsigned int` and an index for any size array (up until `UINT_MAX+1` would not suffice either. Is there a way to sum that's more naive than that?

Comment: @Rafe: that is not a temporary array. Summing the numbers 1 through `n-1` does not require first putting them in an array, even if you forget the formula to do it.

Comment: Incorrect even ignoring the complexity.  The array has n elements with n-1 out of n different values.  This means that not only is one of the values from 0 to n-1 duplicated, but a different value in that range is *missing*.  But the problem can still be solved with O(1) space (not counting the input) and O(n) time.

Comment: @Aaron: It's not quite as bad as I stated, especially since the integers being summed are in the range `0` to `n`. But in general, The sum of `n` fixed-size integers is `O(log n)` (not `O(n)` as I previously wrote) in space.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko:consider the when element 5 is repeated.Does your logic works ?

Comment: @aschepler: You might be onto something. I read the problem as the values being taken from the range 1 through `n-1`, but indeed it says 0 through `n-1`. It seems like there should be a missing element in addition to a duplicated element.

Comment: @Jagan: Yes. `1+2+3+4+5=15. 1+2+3+4+5+5=20. 20-15=5. 5 is a duplicate.`

Comment: @Vlad: If `n=6`, then the values are taken from the range 0 to 5. What if another value had been omitted instead of the 0 being omitted?

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko:1+2+3+4+5=15. 1+1+2+3+4=11.  15-11=4. Is 4 duplicate ?

Comment: @Jagan: You are breaking 'distinct range' requirement here.

Comment: @R.. Good point. 0 can mess up stuff here. Don't know how to deal with that yet. Gotta work tomorrow so I go to bed.

Comment: @Jagan: With Vlad's algorithm, S1=1+2+3+4=10 and S2=1+1+2+3+4=11. S2-S1=1. However it only works because the omitted element was 0.

Comment: @R.. OK, the final idea is that if ARRAY[ABS(SUM2-SUM1)] == 0, then answer is 0, otherwise ABS(SUM2-SUM1). Now I can sleep :)

Comment: In general, S2-S1 is equal to the duplicated element minus the missing element. I don't see how knowing this difference helps you quickly find the value of the duplicated element, however.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: No. The approach you suggested does not work, regardless of how you spin it. One value `A` is missing, another value `B` is duplicated (basically, substituted instead of `A`). That will increase the sum by `B - A`. That's what you find by your algorithm: the `B - A` value. However, knowing `B - A` is still not enough to determine neither `B` nor `A`. Knowing that the sum has increased by 2 would mean that 5 was replaced by 7 (7 is duplicated), or that 1 was replaced by 3 (3 is duplicated) or lots of other possibilities.

Comment: (By "increase" I mead "change": the value of `B - A` can be negative, of course).

Comment: See my answer. It's based on Vlad's, but fixing up the problem that you only know the difference of the missing and duplicate numbers and not their values.

Comment: This just gives X-Y , you can check my answer which uses another condition for the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

`XOR` all the elements together, then `XOR` the result with `XOR([0..n-1])`.

This gives you `missing XOR repeat`; since `missing!=repeat`, at least one bit is set in `missing XOR repeat`.

Pick one of those set bits. Iterate over all the elements again, and only `XOR` elements with that bit set. Then iterate from `1` to `n-1` and `XOR` those numbers that have that bit set.

Now, the value is either the repeated value or the missing value. Scan the elements for that value. If you find it, it's the repeated element. Otherwise, it's the missing value so `XOR` it with `missing XOR repeat`.

Comment: Another `O(n log n)` approach, but completely different from mine. :-)

Comment: @R.. Are you sure this isn't linear complexity?

Comment: Actually I think you're right. I read it as an iterative approach where you peel off a bit at a time, but indeed there are only 2 passes over the array and 2 passes over the values `1` to `n-1`. So I think this is the answer!

Comment: The last pass can be eliminated. When you are making the first pass, calculate the sum `S` (per Vlad) together with your XOR. The sign of the `S - SUM(0...n-1)` will tell you whether the missing is greater or smaller than the repeated. When you are making the second pass, you can also independently XOR the numbers that has that bit *not set* (and the same for numbers in `0...n-1` range). That way you will determine the *second* number as well. I.e. now you know both missing and repeated. Since you know whether the repeated is greater or smaller, you can tell which one is repeated right away.

Comment: @AndreyT: I like your first suggestion, but the second suggestion seems like a waste of time in the loop. It's easier just to do a single XOR operation at the end to get the other value.

Comment: @R..: Yes, you are right. Since we know `missing XOR repeat` and we also know one of them (either `missing` or `repeat`), then a simple XOR will give us the other. No need for a XOR in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Pick two distinct random indexes. If the array values at those indexes are the same, return true.

This operates in constant time. As a bonus, you get the right answer with probability 2/n * 1/(n-1).

Comment: You mean `2/(n*(n-1))`.  Better than you thought!

Comment: How is random constant? The number of expected lookups into the array increases with the array size, which is also known as `O(n)`

Comment: I'm only picking 2 indexes, once. It doesn't usually work - that's the point. An O(1) algorithm that always works is impossible.

Comment: ah, I was assuming you kept trying until you returned true (or checked every index)

Answer (score 1):

O(n) without the temp array.

```
a[]={1,0,0,2,3};
i=0;
int required;
while(i<n)
{
  a[a[i] % n] += n;
  if(a[a[i] % n] >= 2 * n)
    required = a[i] % n;
}
print required;
```

(Assuming of course that n < MAX_INT - 2n)

Comment: I consider this temporary space.

Comment: @R, how do you consider this to use  temp space?

Answer (score 1):

This example could be useful for int, char, and string.

```
char[] ch = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'B' };
Dictionary<char, int> result = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach (char c in ch)
{
   if (result.Keys.Contains(c))
   {
       result[c] = result[c] + 1;
   }
   else
   {
       result.Add(c, 1);
   }
}
foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> pair in result)
{
   if (pair.Value > 1)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
   }
}
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution: Put the elements to `java.util.Set` one by one by `add(E)` until getting `add(E)`==false.

Sorry no constant-time. HashMap:O(N), TreeSet:O(lgN * N).

Comment: O(n) (assuming `java.util.Set` has O(1) cost.)

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth - I don't see how it could be O(1)

Comment: @sje, I was a little sloppy, O(1) insert cost. Python's sets and dicts have O(1) for average case so it's certainly possible. And I'm referring to time complexity because that's what OP originally said. It's obvious that this breaks the requirement for O(1) additional space.

Comment: Depends on whether the Set implementation is a HashSet or a TreeSet.  With a TreeSet, you have O(lg n) insert cost, but presumably here you would use a HashSet, which should have O(1) amortized insert cost, if tell it the expected capacity (which you know) and possibly the load factor (though the default likely will suffice)

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth O(1) per element, but you have to insert `n` elements.

Comment: @Mark which means O(n) which is exactly what I said.

Comment: Only Java fans would really *get into* discussing data structures that are nowhere near `O(1)` space as part of an in-place-computation puzzle...

Comment: @James: you are right, it should be depended on whether the Set implementation.

Comment: @R Leave it to non java fans to be egotistical about their language choice?  This is a traditional question.  My favorite (hacky) answer is still:  
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] < 0) { 
    return array[i]; // Dupe, we already negated this one
  }
  array[i] = -array[i];
}
Voila.  Constant space, linear time.

Comment: @James: nope, that's not constant space. It's `O(n)` space because you're assuming your input buffer has extra unused writable bits that you can use as temporary space. Whatever the size of your data type is, I can make `n` large enough that you don't have an extra bit.

Comment: @R Damn you and your logic! I accept your argument, but only if you bother to define the original array as unsigned, which most of the people asking don't think to do in advance (hence it generally sufficing, since they're giving N between 0 and some number :)

Comment: Here's where I'm supposed to make another cheap stab at Java for not having unsigned types.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Build a lookup table.  Lookup.  Done.

Non-temporary array solution:

Build lookup into gate array hardware, invoke.

Comment: Wouldn't that involve a temporary array?

Comment: Huge temporary storage for sure... but it is constant size!

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do is `O(n log n)` in time and `O(1)` in space:

The basic idea is to perform a binary search of the *values* `0` through `n-1`, passing over the whole array of `n` elements at each step.

1. Initially, let `i=0`, `j=n-1` and `k=(i+j)/2`.
2. On each run through the array, sum the elements whose values are in the range `i` to `k`, and count the number of elements in this range.
3. If the sum is equal to `(k-i)*(k-i+1)/2 + i*(k-i+1)`, then the range `i` through `k` has neither the duplicate nor the omitted value. If the count of elements is less than `k-i+1`, then the range has the omitted value but not the duplicate. In either case, replace `i` by `k+1` and `k` by the new value of `(i+j)/2`.
4. Else, replace `j` by `k` and `k` by the new value of `(i+j)/2`.
5. If `i!=j`, goto 2.

The algorithm terminates with `i==j` and both equal to the duplicate element.

(Note: I edited this to simplify it. The old version could have found either the duplicate or the omitted element, and had to use Vlad's difference trick to find the duplicate if the initial search turned up the omitted value instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @sje's answer. Worst case is 2 passes through the array, no additional storage, non destructive.

O(n) without the temp array.

```
a[]={1,0,0,2,3};
i=0;
int required;
while (a[a[i] % n] < n)    
   a[a[i++] % n] += n;

required = a[i] % n;
while (i-->0)
   a[a[i]%n]-=n;

print required;
```

(Assuming of course that n < MAX_INT/2)